# Update entrie X in table Y by entrie Z in table A when entrie X exist in table A AND keep the entries in the other column as they are

Tags: mysql

I have a table Y with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght (X). I want to update the entrie X in table Y when entrie X exists in another table (A) with the entrie in the other table (Z) AND keep the entries in the other columns as they are.

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+-------------------------------++-------++----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||Andrea || 29 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||Oscar  || 38 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||James  || 44 |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||Julia  || 57 |
```

And table B contained:

```
|col 1                          ||col 2                          |
+-------------------------------++-------------------------------+
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||20161217_LC_YoBirthdayYES_A_DE |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||20160227_NL_Luxus_1_FR         |
```

I want a query that will change col 1 in table A as:

```
|col1                           ||col2  ||col3|
+-------------------------------++------++----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||Andrea|| 29 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayYES_A_DE ||Oscar || 38 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||James || 44 |
|20160227_NL_Luxus_1_FR         ||Julia || 57 |
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem... :/ 
-> Maybe it will work with `Update` and `INNER JOIN` (like a problem I had already in the past) - but I´m not 100% sure...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe it will work with `Update` and `INNER JOIN`

Bingo!

```
UPDATE TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col1
SET    TableA.col1 = TableB.col2
```

Comment: Not inner join instead of join in your answer?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: `JOIN` (without any qualification to the contrary) is shorthand for `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: My falt... I'm not quite awake today... Thanks for your help!